# How to avoid easy closing of a shinyWidgets::dropdown()?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinywidgets

I would like to close a dropdown only when clicking a button within it. I tried like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
            return false;
          });
          
          $('#closeDropdownBtn').click(function() {
            $('.dropdown').removeClass('show');
          });
        });
      ")
    )
  ),
  
  dropdown(
    "Your contents goes here ! You can pass several elements",
    circle = TRUE, status = "danger", icon = icon("gear"), width = "300px",
    animate = animateOptions(enter = "fadeInDown", exit = "fadeOutUp", duration = 1),
    actionButton("closeDropdownBtn", "Fechar Dropdown")
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like the dropdown to close only with this button, and not when I click on another element on the screen, whatever it may be. Also, how to create an overlay on the screen when the dropdown is present, just like with a modal. I would like to replicate this behavior in the dropdown:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  showModal(
    
    modalDialog(
      
      "TEXT",
      
      actionButton("id1", "Close"),
      
      easyClose = FALSE
      
    )
    
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$id1, {
    
    removeModal()
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dropdown` function from **shinyWidgets** does not create a Bootstrap dropdown. The Bootstrap dropdown can be obtained with `dropdownButton`. If you use `dropdownButton`, then this code works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
    alert("test");
  });

  $(".dropdown").on("click", "#closeDropdownBtn", function() {
    $(".dropdown").dropdown("toggle");
  });
});
```

Note that the selector of your `closeDropdownBtn` in the definition of the "`onclick`" event is "deferred". This is needed because this button is not visible when the app is initialized.

You can also toggle this Bootstrap dropdown from R with the **shinyWidgets** function `toggleDropdownButton`.

Now if you replace `alert("test")` with `return false`, this will work but then there is a problem: this will also work when clicking the button, so the button will no longer play its role. Here is a solution to this problem:

```r
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var btnHasBeenClicked = false;
          $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
            if(!btnHasBeenClicked) {
              return false; 
            } else {
              btnHasBeenClicked = false;
            }
          });
          
          $('.dropdown').on('click', '#closeDropdownBtn', function() {
            btnHasBeenClicked = true;
            $('.dropdown').dropdown('toggle');
          });
        });
      ")
    )
  )
```